# ACCESS QUERY MORE THAN 1 million records,not able to export

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query which pulls all records in a db, the criteria I have put is as per trust, but some trusts have data more that 1 million records, for which error is coming to split the records, the only field I can split is year, but stupidly I have uploaded dates as APR2016..JAN2017 etc as text. Can somebody help me write criteria where to as for the year 2016 or 2017 and pull records accordingly.

this is the current query
SELECT Database.[Org Code], Database.[Invoice Number], Database.[Amount Tax], Database.[Vendor Name], Database.Link, Database.MonthOfEntry

MonthOfEntry is the field where the year is updated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the `MonthOfEntry` is field is always MMMYYYY, you may be able to do this:

```
SELECT [Org Code], [Invoice Number], [Amount Tax], [Vendor Name], Link, MonthOfEntry
FROM TableName
WHERE Right(MonthOfEntry, 4) = '2017';
```

I'm not sure how well it will perform, but that would be one way to restrict the records.

(as an aside, I should mention that normalization is often a large contender in how this type of stuff is handled, though I do realize that it's not always feasible to import fully normalized data...)

Also as an aside, I don't believe there's any particular limit on the number of rows returned in a query.  Rather, I suspect the error you're receiving is due to the method of export.  An alternative may be to do a code-based export rather than relying on some of the build-in commands, which are sometimes quirky.

Comment: Thanks jdl for the quick answer..and you are correct about the export thing . The error is coming while exporting the data. The query looks great, but I am getting error 'syntax error at FROM Clause.Can you please check my syntax belowSELECT Database.[Org Code], Database.[Invoice Number], Database.[Amount Tax], Database.[Vendor Name], Database.Link, Database.MonthOfEntry
FROM Database
WHERE Right(MonthOfEntry,4)='2017';

Comment: I experimented little bit and got the answer. WHERE Right(Database.MonthOfEntery,4=2017.........Thanks again for all your help jdl